# Counting the array spots visited by binary searches (Java)

Tags: java, binary-search

So the idea was to find out how many times each array component is considered by binary search when we search all possible needles for the haystack:

```
package com.github.coderodde.fun.binarysearch;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearchSpotCounter {

    public static int binarySearch(int[] haystack, int needle, int[] counter) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = haystack.length - 1;
        
        while (left < right) {
            int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
            
            counter[middle]++;
            
            if (haystack[middle] == needle) {
                return middle;
            }
            
            if (needle < haystack[middle]) {
                right = middle - 1;
            } else {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
        }
        
        return left;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] haystack = new int[20];
        int[] counters = new int[haystack.length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i) {
            haystack[i] = i;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(binarySearch(haystack, i, counters));
        }
        
        System.out.println("Counts: " + Arrays.toString(counters));
    }
}
```

The output was:

```
Counts: [0, 4, 2, 0, 9, 0, 4, 2, 0, 20, 0, 4, 2, 0, 10, 2, 0, 5, 2, 0]
```

**Critique request**

As always, all critique is welcome. (Is there funkier ways to achieve the same?)

Comment: I rather enjoy funk as a design goal. Keep doing that stuff[!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_That_Stuff)

Answer (score 4):

Don't you think it's quite strange some counters remain zero? Like you can *find* a needle without *looking at* it...

Your code narrows down the search area 'till it becomes 1-item only, so you can return that single index and - thanks to the initial quiet assumption the array contains consecutive integer values - this index certainly indicates the correct value. In real applications, however, we usually have non-consecutive values of keys, so the real binary search must also return a special value for the *'not found'* result, like, say, minus one.

Then the tail of the function would look like

```
    return haystack[left] == needle ? left : NOT_FOUND;
```

which deserves expanding to

```
    counters[left]++;
    return haystack[left] == needle ? left : NOT_FOUND;
```

as we actually visit the item to be returned.

Comment: Zero counters... Point.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding API design, you have made a single use throwaway implementation. Instead of passing the `counter` array as a parameter, I would make the search algorithm accept a single plain old `java.util.List` that contains the data and if I then wanted to count the number of times each element is accessed, I would wrap the actual list that contains the data with a List implementation that does the counting in it's `get(int)` method without the search algorithm knowing anything about it.

This removes the responsibility of counting from the search algorithm, staying true to single responsibility principle. It also gives you more flexibility in recording the access. You could for example timestamp each one so that you can visualize the search later by just changing the List implementation.

I understand that you are not doing algorithm analysis, but from that point of view the array access is not as interesting as the number of comparisons (in the original code you record only one array access but you perform two comparisons). Integers can be deceiving as the comparisons are so effective. But if you used a generic `List` and a `Comparator` it would be easier to spot that you are making the same comparison twice to essentially get the same result between the needle and the middle element (-1, 0 or 1).

Once you are not restricted by primitive arrays, you could even connect the `List` and the `Comparator` and record which list elements are fetched and which are compared in which stage. Endless possibilities. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `binarySearch` code considers two cases: either the input (part of) array is 1-item long, or it's longer.

In the case of a single item, that item is returned (and its respective counter ought to be incremented, as I pointed out in my first answer).

Otherwise, the middle item is determined, its counter is incremented and its value tested. If the *needle* value is found, its position is returned, else the search continues in a left or right subarray – but that middle item is never touched again.
As a result, the middle item of the `haystack` array is touched (and its counter incremented) exactly once per `binarySearch()` call, and as you search for each item exactly once the middle item's counter eventually equals the `haystack`'s length.

And similarly for the middle element of each recursively defined left or right subarray.

Conlusion: to reproduce the result it's enough to binary-split the given range recursively and assign the length of each subrange to its middle term's counter.

```
    public static void binaryCount(int[] haystack, int[] counter) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = haystack.length - 1;
        
        binaryCount(left, right, counter);
    }
    
    public static void binaryCount(int left, int right, int[] counter) {
        int len = right - left + 1;
        
        if (len > 0) {
            int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
            
            counter[middle] = len;
        
            if (len > 1) {
                binaryCount(left, middle - 1, counter);
                binaryCount(middle + 1, right, counter);
            }
        }
    }
```

You may test the complete code at OnlineGDB: https://onlinegdb.com/Oohb4NCyl

I've expanded your original method by an additional parameter `boolean fixSingleItemCount` to fix zero counters at single-item ranges,
and I call it twice, with the parameter value being `false` and `true` (results are accumulated in `counters1` and `counters2`, respectively).
Finally, the `binaryCount` method is called and its results are printed (`counters3`).

**Edit**
Actually, the `if (len > 1)` condition can be removed. It was meant to allow recursive calls on non-negative length subarrays only, but that case would be handled anyway by the `if (len > 0)` condition, one level deeper in the recursion.